# Add a preloader to rmarkdown HTML output [flexdashboard]

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown, preloader

I have a relatively complex `flexdashboard` which takes some time to load.

Does anyone have experience with adding a preloader to `flex_dashboard` output?

For instance, adding any of [these](https://medium.muz.li/top-30-most-captivating-preloaders-for-your-website-95ed1beff99d) would be great for me. While I know how to add a `gif`, I'm wondering how to stop displaying it at website load.

Is anything like that possible within `rmarkdown` as well as `flex_dashboard`?

Comment: Are you kniting that to an html document or using `runtime: shiny`?

Comment: @JohnCoene, kniting to HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this codepen](https://codepen.io/mimoYmima/pen/fisgL) in RMarkdown.

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) url('https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/107759/screenshots/2436386/copper-loader.gif') no-repeat center 20%;
}
```

::: {#preloader}
:::

```{js, echo=FALSE}
$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();});
  });
});
```

A solution inspired by codepen: <https://codepen.io/mimoYmima/pen/fisgL>.
````

This solution requires Pandoc 2. For Pandoc < 2, replace

```
::: {#preloader}
:::
```

with `<div id="preloader"></div>`

Comment: Thanks @romles! However, I still cannot get this to run within a flexdashboard; it just doesn't appear while the pages is loading, it only appears once the page has loaded. Any ideas why? Probably this is a collusion with flexdashboard's source code, and I'll need some further tinkering with the package code to get it to work.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear for me that you want to deal with a flexdashboard. This is surely a collision with the flexdashboard source code. I don't know it very much. I will have a look.

Comment: Yes, my fault - I've corrected the post now. If you have any ideas that'd be great - I've already tried with different methods (including external .css, .js, .html files in YAML, inserting them into chunks, etc.), but to no avail.

Comment: I have no heavy flexdashboard to test. A suggestion: include the `div` with the `before_body` argument. If it is not clear, I can explain more.

Comment: Thanks a lot - however, have tried it, but wasn't successful. It seems like something in the dashboard source code prevents loading any part before all of them are loaded. I think I'll need to have a look there; if you'll have any suggestions, let me know.

Comment: maybe try to put the `#preloader` CSS rules in an external file and call it with the `css` argument.

Comment: Tried as well. It seems that any pre-defined option doesn't really work in that case.